# 'Unexpected token' error using await keyword

Tags: javascript, async-await, ecmascript-next

I am trying to write a function using the `await` keyword (using Babel) that makes use of the [pg-promise library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-promise) inside of a `for` loop.

```
import postgres from 'pg-promise';
const pgp = postgres();
const db = pgp(<config options>);
const array = <some array of objects>

for (const element of array) {
    try {
        let test = await db.query('INSERT INTO <table> (name) VALUES (${name})', { name: element.name });
        console.log('test: ', test);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error," err);
    }
}
```

However, I keep getting a syntax error that the `db` referant is an `Unexpected token`. What is the correct way to use the `await` keyword in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that this is because you need to declare a function as `async` before you can use `await`

```
import postgres from 'pg-promise';
const pgp = postgres();
const db = pgp(<config options>);
const array = [<some array of objects>]

const runQuery = async (array)=> {
    try{
        for (const element of array) {
            const test = await db.query('INSERT INTO <table> (name) VALUES (${name})', { name: element.name });
            return test;
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("error," err);
    }
}

runQuery.then((test)=>console.log('test: ', test)).catch(...)
```

Comment: Unrelated, but in your example, passing in formatting parameter as `element` would be the same as passing in `{ name: element.name }`, because that element already has property `name` that you are using ;)

Comment: Just so, since you are using ES6, you could do the same without Babel, by replacing async with generator, and using `yield` instead of `await`, because this is what Babel does anyway, it simply translates their own commands into those. See [example](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#tasks).

Answer (score 0):

Make the calling function `async` as well.

Comment: What about function calling that function? Is it only 1 level up from await?